# Why am I getting 46 errors with this for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am looking for all the even numbers from 1 through 100.

```
n <- seq(from = 1, to = 100)
for (x in n) {if(n %% 2 == 0) print(n)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we need 'x' instead of 'n' as 'n' is the whole vector

```
for(x in n) if(x %% 2 == 0) print(x)
```

#### data

```
n <- seq(from = 1, to = 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

As Akrun has already pointed out, you needed `x %% 2`, not `n %% 2`... note I've use `i`

```
n <- 1:100
for(i in n){
  if(i %% 2 == 0){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

However, if you want the even numbers in your sequence you could just use:

```
n[n %% 2 == 0]
```

---

Note also that you got warnings not errors, they're subtly different